# Salesforce Gem for Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, salesforce

I have this rails Application which uses salesforce App. I want to know if there are any gem and tutorials to build Salesforce App in rails easily. I found this rforcedotcom gem but it lacks tutorial for Rails 3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current standard gem is the [databasedotcom](https://github.com/heroku/databasedotcom) gem, which is updated fairly actively and officially endorsed by Salesforce.

There is also the [asf-rest-adapter](https://github.com/raygao/asf-rest-adapter) gem (which has a dependency on asf-soap-adapter) by Ray Gao which I have running in a number of apps, and works quite well.

Comment: Also, where could I find client_id and client_secret on salesforce

Comment: Bhushan - In Salesforce (assuming similar for Database.com) they're in Setup -> Develop -> Remote Access. You create a new application in there, specify the various required settings for your app and then it provides the details you need.

Comment: Looks like the databasedotcom (and REST APIs) only allow you to integrate with Enterprise and above clients.  Are you seeing that as well?

Comment: does anyone know if the asf-rest-adaptor works with rails 3.017?

Comment: rmw- Salesforce only allows API access for Enterprise and above, so you can't connect remotely to any lower instance. This is a Salesforce limitation not a gem one.

Answer (score 4):

There's yet another gem out now called [Restforce](https://github.com/ejholmes/restforce).
The author bills it as "lighter weight" with "greater flexibility and more advanced functionality" than the databasedotcom gem (and he should know -- he worked on the that gem too).

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to use [Active Force](https://rubygems.org/gems/active_force) that uses RestForce as a backend and provides an ActiveRecord like interface. It also have some generators to get up and running faster.